# Autofill state and postcode according to the city in magento checkout page

Tags: magento, postal-code

Hi guys i have searched for it a lot but didn't find a good solution of it. I want to auto fill the postcode and state of Australia after customer enters their city in magento checkout page.What would be the best way to achieve this?Can you recommend some extensions if there is any or suggest some solutions. I tried to use the extension of Fontis but it didn't work.
So guys can someone help.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution of my question.As there is no answer provided i thought my answer may be helpful.At first my main problem is to create a table with the Australian postcodes, suburb and state. For that i googled a lot and after all i got the csv file of all these information. I filtered it according to my requirement.

Here is the link to the csv file that consist of Australian postcodes, suburb and state. [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B68AKIPHfh1JSVJYUHQ2YWtuaEE/view?usp=sharing).

Now you can use this csv to create a table in a database which further is used in autocomplete.

All the codes that i have used may not be usable in your case so i didn't care to put it.

But i think this will help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to get into more complexity of code, here is a solution for you.

**First Step**:

download latest country zip code Excel file and locate that excel file under root folder.

**Second Step:**

Call ajax function in the last part of billing.phtml (../template/persistent/checkout/onepage/)

```
<script src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=”text/javascript”><br>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(‘.postcode‘).blur(function(){ //.postcode class of zipcode text field
var s = jQuery(this).val();
jQuery.ajax({
type: ‘POST’,
url:“http://www.sample.com/postcode.php“, //file which read zip code excel     file
dataType: “json”, //is used for return multiple values
data: { ‘s’ : s },
success: function(data){
try {
jQuery(“.state“).val(data.state); //region-class of state text field
jQuery(“.city“).val(data.dist);//city-class of city text filed
} catch (e) {
alert(e.Message);
}
},
error:function (xhr, status, err){
alert( “status=” + xhr.responseText + “, error=” + err );
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

This Ajax function will call “http://www.sample.com/postcode.php” file

Under postcode.php file we have to read excel file and return state and city value

**postcode.php**

```
<?php
extract ($_POST);
$s=$_POST[‘s’];  //get value from ajax
$filename=”zip.csv“; //zipcode csv file(must reside in same folder)
$f = fopen($filename, “r”);
while ($row = fgetcsv($f))
{
if ($row[1] == $s) //1 mean number of column of zipcode
 {
  $district=$row[3];  //3- Number of city column
  $state=$row[4]; //4-Number of state column
  break;
 }
}
fclose($f);
echo json_encode(
 array(“dist” => $district,
 “state” => $state,
 “zip” => $s)
);  //Pass those details by json
?>
```

That’s All, Enjoy